# Routing Redirect Controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my routes.php file in codeigniter I have set it up so if my config item maintenance is set to true it will make that as the default controller.

`$config['maintenance'] = TRUE;`

route.php

```
if (!$this->config->item('installed')) {

    $route['default_controller'] = "install/step_1/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';

} else {

    if ($this->config->item('maintenance') == TRUE) {
        $route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/maintenance/index";
        $route['404_override'] = '';
    } else {
        $route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/home/index";
        $route['404_override'] = '';
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that. When it is set to TRUE When I am logged in as admin I would still like the home controller as default controller. I can not seem to make it work.

**Maintenance Controller.**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maintenance extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        if ($this->config->item('maintenance')) {

            $this->load->library('user');

            if(!$this->user->isLogged()) {
                $this->info();
            } else {

                // Should Allow Me To View Home Controller 
            }

        }


    }

    public function info() {
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '/template/common/maintenance.php')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->configs->get('config_template') . '/template/common/maintenance');
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/common/maintenance');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded this hmvc $this->load->module and it has seemed to work

```
public function index() {

        if ($this->config->item('maintenance')) {

            $this->load->library('user');

            if(!$this->user->isLogged()) {

                $this->info();

            } else {

                $this->load->module('catalog/common/home');
                $this->home->index();

            }

        }


    }
```